# Ubuntu logs me out when using unity / compiz session

Tags: unity, logout

I'm currently running Ubuntu 17.10 and yesterday (28/11/2017) after updating a lot of packets the problem appeared.

When I use the Unity session I automatically get logged out under these conditions:

- When I hover with my mouse over any icon of the sidebar.
- When I press the `alt` key. (I can't even do `alt+tab`).
- When I press the `super` key.

I've tried many of the commands proposed in [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) . But with no success (and loosing some of my fine tuned settings).

I also uninstalled and reinstalled unity.

running `dmesg` after this logout happens I get following information:

```
compiz[10616]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fbca309feeb sp 00007fff5f59a4d0 error 4 in i965_dri.so[7fbca2af6000+7e4000]
```

Comment: Answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults
Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1735594

Comment: Thank's for the comment, the packages from paulo-miguel-dias's repository work fine. It was me who made the this bug report on launchpad. I missed the comment with the repository.