# Ubuntu 16.04 Jan 3 2018 update causing screen/access issues "The Dell E4310 that hides Icons"

Tags: unity, icons

New to "Buntu" (as my G Kid sez) though a thousand years ago I did work with SCO Unix.

After the update of Jan 18 I'm having screen instability. When I hover the mouse over the side or top icons, the screen blanks, clears off EVERYTHING, blanks again and then repopulates after 1-2 sec.

I can't open terminal via the icon, only through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and I only can open any other icon by double clicking REALLY fast.

I rolled back the update the reinstalled the full package again, no help.

Drivers for the graphics card?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-latest-updates-compiz-segfaults