# Kernel 4.4.0-108 breaks system

Tags: kernel

On my HP Microserver (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) I updated an hour ago to the latest kernel (4.4.0-108-generic). After that the system won't start. I 'Grubbed' into 4.4.0-104 and it boots without problems.
Anyone else have the same experience?

I noticed later that someone else has already mentioned this (i.e. possibly the same problem) in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1742323. My apologies.

Comment: I am sorry you have this problem but it is unlikely you can fix this yourself, although you can try. Best off running an old kernel for now and filing on the bug report that this affects you as well. The alternate is to try to compile a custom kernel or perhaps even patch the kernel source yourself, and I would not necessarily discourage you from doing so, but there is a bit of a learning curve and custom kernels tend to be poorly supported here.

Comment: It is helpful to know what type of computer you have. For example the last automatic Ubuntu LTS meltdown (pardon the pun) occurred only on 4th and 5th Generation Intel CPUs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults

Comment: HP Microserver gen8, Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU G1610T, 4GB RAM

Comment: Where is the question? Looking for other affected users is not acceptable. Please note this is a Q&A site, not a forum.