# 4.13 kernel update for Meltdown wrecks graphics drivers on old netbook

Tags: 16.04, kernel, graphics, lubuntu, intel-graphics

Today I updated my old 32 bit Lubuntu 16.04 netbook from the 4.10 kernel to the 4.13 kernel per an automatic update pushed out for the Meltdown issue. Unfortunately this resulted in booting to a black screen.  My graphics is Intel 945 GME x86  MMX SSE 2, graphics driver 1.4 Mesa 17.3.1 from the padoka PPA.

Something is wrong right from the git-go: I turned off quiet splash in grub and the text display during boot does not fit the screen, the lowest line is off the bottom of the screen.

I can drop back to the old kernel and everything is fine.

I looked at the canonical question [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it?s=2|161.2258); the path through that leads me to the conclusion that it was caused by the kernel update, which I knew.

Is there a fix for this graphics problem under the new kernel?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Lubuntu 16.04, thanks, I will edit question to include that.

Comment: I think you can downgrade kernel to 4.4.0-109-generic (`linux-image-generic`). What is bad with Mesa from official repository?

Comment: Mainline kernel for Ubuntu 16.04 is `4.4.0-109` which patches `Meltdown` https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support

Comment: Nothing probably, I thought the problem might be an issue I've been reading about with old Intel graphics so I applied the fix for that.  Since it didn't help, I plan to PPA-purge it.

Comment: You probably hit by this bug https://askubuntu.com/questions/994134/kernel-4-4-0-108-breaks-system

Comment: Kernel 4.4.0-109 works, thanks for the suggestion. If you care to write it up as an answer, I will accept it.