# Disappearing Icons

Tags: compiz, icons

I am running 16.04.3 and have started having problems.
All was well until I had to turn off my laptop.
When it was switched back on all was fine for about 10 mins when all of the icons on my screen started disappearing by sliding off to the left when the curser hovered over or when I tried to click on them.
I have tried a complete new install of the latest version (on a formatted clean drive). Within 5 mins the icons once again started 'sliding' off the screen.
I typed "ubuntu-bug" into the Terminal and it came up with "/usr/bin/compiz" missing. I have no idea what that means or how to fix it. 
Any help would be appreciated but please bear in mind that I am a user not a geeky tech type.

Comment: What do you get when you type `apt list compiz`?

Comment: This issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults?