# Ubuntu 16.04.3-server desktop: black screen after upgrade

Tags: 16.04, server, gnome, xorg, arm

I installed the [Ubuntu-16.04.3-server-arm64](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/16.04.3/release/ubuntu-16.04.3-server-arm64.iso) (hwe) on my ARM64 server.

[image]

Then I execute:

```
apt update && apt dist-upgrade && apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then I `reboot`. However, I can't see anything about desktop, I even can't see the ubuntu logo, which should have appeared before user login interface. But `ssh` on it is possible. So I think it's the problem of desktop.

I just checked the xorg log, there are some errors but I don't know what to do:

[image]

Here is the info about the graphics card:

[image]

Comment: Related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix   Maybe. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that upgrading the kernel can invoke this bug, which means that for now I can't upgrade the kernel from 4.10.0 to 4.13.0.

I've found an error saying that `Failed to load module "fbdev"` in the log of Xorg

Here is what I've done to solve this issue:

```
apt update
apt-mark hold linux-generic-hwe-16.04
apt-mark hold linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04
apt-mark hold linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
apt dist-upgrade
apt install ubuntu-desktop
apt install xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04 && reboot
```

I don't know why but somehow `apt install ubuntu-desktop` doesn't install xserver-hwe packages automatically, whereas ubuntu16.04 on X86 do it automatically.

Maybe it's because I didn't upgrade the kernel?