# Ubuntu 16.04, Periodic Keyboard Crash, Mouse Works, Have to force reboot

Tags: keyboard, bug-reporting, ideapad

So I've looked at some other posts about keyboards crashing in Ubuntu 16.04, but they don't seem to have quite the same problem I'm having.

[Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 keep freezing randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly)

My situation is interesting because the keyboard, and only the keyboard crashes. Mouse still can move the cursor, and left click/right click still perform expected operations. The added bonus is that when this happens, I have to force reboot. The normal reboot hangs indefinitely, forcing me to hold down the power button.

My system is a Lenovo Ideapad with an i7 Quad-Core processor, a Nvidia dedicated graphics, 12gb ram, M2 SSD and Sata SSD.

Detailed hardware details:

```
lenovo-ideapad-y700-15isk
    description: Notebook
    product: 80NV (LENOVO_MT_80NV_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK
    serial: PF0D4BSZ
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled chassis=notebook family=IDEAPAD frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_80NV_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK uuid=11C8ECF5-6963-E511-BA4C-507B9D456BF4
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Allsparks 5A
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: SDK0J40709 WIN
       serial: PF0D4BSZ
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: 0
          version: CDCN25WW
          date: 09/04/2015
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 6080KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 3099MHz
          capacity: 3500MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 6MiB
             capacity: 6MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 5
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1c
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 12GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: HMA451S6AFR8N-TF
             vendor: SK Hynix
             physical id: 0
             serial: 37257723
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: SODIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: HMA41GS6AFR8N-TF
             vendor: SK Hynix
             physical id: 2
             serial: 81393322
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 3
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:93000000-93ffffff ioport:80000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a2
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:129 memory:93000000-93ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:130 memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:94300000-9430ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.13.0-31-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Audio device
                   product: AT2005USB
                   vendor: Audio-Technica
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-1.10 audio-control
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: Microsoft
                   vendor: Microsoft
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@1:3
                   version: 6.34
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Video
                   product: Lenovo EasyCamera
                   vendor: NXP (Philips Semi, Signetics)
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@1:6
                   version: 12.18
                   serial: 200901010001
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: b
                   bus info: usb@1:b
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.13.0-31-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.13
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:131 memory:9432a000-9432afff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:127 memory:94328000-94329fff memory:9432d000-9432d0ff ioport:5080(size=8) ioport:5088(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:9432b000-9432b7ff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 memory:94200000-942fffff
           *-generic
                description: SD Host controller
                product: SD/MMC Card Reader Controller
                vendor: O2 Micro, Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:94201000-94201fff memory:94200000-942007ff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 memory:94100000-941fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 8260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
                logical name: wlp8s0
                version: 3a
                serial: a4:34:d9:2e:13:b4
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-31-generic firmware=31.560484.0 ip=192.168.0.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:132 memory:94100000-94101fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:125 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:94000000-940fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                logical name: enp9s0
                version: 15
                serial: 50:7b:9d:45:6b:f4
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:128 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94004000-94004fff memory:94000000-94003fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H PMC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:94324000-94327fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:133 memory:94320000-94323fff memory:94310000-9431ffff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Sunrise Point-H SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:9432c000-9432c0ff ioport:5040(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: SAMSUNG MZNLN256
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 3L0Q
             serial: S22YNXAG923352
             size: 238GiB (256GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=2742465a-f2e0-4434-9cc7-b9086a74a122 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: 3b8a-3e98
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI System Partition state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 00360d30-bf3f-43de-a904-6fdecf9ae5b3
                size: 226GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2018-01-14 15:55:20 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2018-01-25 14:44:02 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2018-01-25 14:44:03 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 1
                serial: 0ed1f940-bfba-4438-9c09-778054bfcfb9
                size: 11GiB
                capacity: 11GiB
                capabilities: nofs precious readonly hidden nomount swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: Crucial_CT525MX3
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: R040
             serial: 1703157E8D44
             size: 489GiB (525GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=8819b526
           *-volume
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                logical name: /media/user/CRUCIAL
                version: 3.1
                serial: b8128075-f5d9-2a48-bcea-0c558c3278f8
                size: 489GiB
                capacity: 489GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2017-03-17 00:22:08 filesystem=ntfs label=CRUCIAL modified_by_chkdsk=true mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=mounted upgrade_on_mount=true
```

edit: It happened again today, but this time something different. The last key I had pressed kept continuing on into infinity. (space bar)

output of `uname -r`

```
4.13.0-32-generic
```

output of `apt list --installed | grep microcode`

```
intel-microcode/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 3.20180108.0+really20170707ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

`lsmod | grep peaq` outputs nothing

Comment: Please format terminal output blocks by selecting them and pressing the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: What does `uname -r` report?

Comment: Also what does `apt list --installed | grep microcode` report?

Comment: See edited question. Thanks, @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @TheUnholyProgrammer Looks good so far. Does `lsmod | grep peaq` return anything?

Comment: It returns absolutely nothing

Comment: @TheUnholyProgrammer Afraid of that. If it had output anything the fix would have been to make it go away. The only thing left I can think to try is an earlier kernel from 4.10 or a newer kernel like 14.14.15. Has this problem been happening for a long time or just in January?

Comment: Ever since the installation of Ubuntu. So all of January, yeah.

Comment: @TheUnholyProgrammer January was a disaster: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults and more closer to your problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948 The last link has options for changing the kernel version to 4.10 or 4.14.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Maybe I'm a little confused here, your comment has 3 thumbs up now. Is there something still wrong with how I have the question formatted? I know I used the {} button...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've been reading the post you made on the question you linked me to. I cannot enter grub menu by holding shift upon boot. Is this because I'm using UEFI to boot? That'd make a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: @TheUnholyProgrammer I lost my grub menu a couple of times and had to run [boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc) to get it working properly. If that doesn't fix it then we'd need to look at your `/etc/default/grub` file and check the TIMEOUT values.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix

1. Should I use the recommended repair?
2. If that doesn't work, what should I set the TIMEOUT values to?

Comment: @TheUnholyProgrammer Yes the recommended repair. It keeps life simple. Take note of the pastebin # it gives you when it's done so you can link it later. If the Grub Time Out value is set to 0 then set it to 10 but don't worry about that step just yet.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Have used the recommended repair. Shift key was able to bring up grub. From there, I went to Advanced Options and noticed I had the following versions of the linux kernel: 4.13.0-32, 4.13.0-31, 4.4.0-112.

Not surprisingly, I don't have any kernels I available from before January 10th. Any advice on installing a different linux kernel version? I am looking it up right now.

Also, I plan to install the kernel your guide recommends, 14.14.13.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem. If you connect an external USB keyboard do you get different results?

Comment: @TheUnholyProgrammer Glad to hear grub is working now. You could try `4.4.0-112` to see if that works ok. For my laptop there are WiFi fixes on `4.12.xx` that are missing. If you install from the `14.14.xx` chain don't install `14.14.13` which is two generations old now. Install `14.14.15` which seems to run faster to me and has more bug fixes. In a day or two `14.14.16` will come out with even more bug fixes.

Comment: Also, it looks like I've messed up your version numbering XD. Its kernel `4.14.13`. 

Now I have a rather silly question. On the linux git page, I do not see where you can download anything more specific than `4.14.xxx`. I see `4.14-rcx` though.

Comment: Yes I messed up it's not `14.14.14` it is `4.14.14` and `4.14.15` I've been using successfully recently. Go to this [page](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and press the "End" key to see them.

Comment: @ElderGeek I'll certainly test that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update Lenovo BIOS in Windows

Luckily you still have windows installed on second SSD (`/dev/sdb`) so you can still apply BIOS updates to your laptop. Many users have reported freezing keyboard caused by a BIOS bug. The [solution](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/Lenovo-Y700-keyboard-issue/m-p/3461921#M3754) can only be applied via Windows and it appears there is [no Linux BIOS update](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/My-IdeaPad-Y700-keyboard-often-goes-unresponsive-Linux-Ubuntu/m-p/3525578) for that bug.

## Update Intel Microcode for Linux

Getting the latest Intel Microcode in Ubuntu / Linux is a good idea when you are having problems:

[image: Additional Drivers]

From Ubuntu Software Settings check the bottom option **Intel Microcode** to enable support on your next boot.

## Go back to older kernel or get Latest 4.14.xx Kernel

Many Ubuntu users reported problems with the Meltdown patches that were rushed out at the beginning of 2018 forcing Kernel 4.10.0-42 users to Kernel 4.13.0-26 ahead of schedule.

You can read more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948).

Comment: What are the chances this would solve the problem when this problem was completely non-exist when I used to have windows on this very same machine? It ran without any crashing for like a year or so and I'm pretty certain I updated the bios right after the machine was shipped.

Comment: The BIOS update in Windows is the first common step for everyone using the Lenovo 700 laptop. After that the answer lists the next steps to take. But you should definitely check if a new BIOS update has come out for your laptop since your last update not just for bug fixes but speed improvements and better support of NVMe, SATA, screen, USB, etc.

Comment: Alright, I'll be working on it. Also, I don't actually have windows installed on that secondary SSD, that's just a lot of data I didn't want to go without. The drive is still dos format since I haven't gotten around to changing that. However, I have the means to install windows, so I can easily install it/boot from a usb to resolve this issue.

After I make all of these system changes (will take quite a bit of time), and the machine runs consistently without crash I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @TheUnholyProgrammer If you don't have Windows working I don't think it's worth the effort of reinstalling it just to get the BIOS updated. Apparently some users had problems with Lenovo update for Meltdown / Spectre protection so there is a chance it could be detrimental at this stage: https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/solutions/len-18282