# GUI/Unity crashing in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, compiz, crash

In reference to question [GUI/Unity crashing in 16.04 LTS after updates 2018-01-04, compiz segfaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults) I want to add more information:

The referenced problem occured on my dad's laptop, and applying the trick from above's answer helped - but only for a day.  Today I got another phone call and after logging in to the machine I saw this "`-lowgfx`" suffix had magically re-appeared in that file.

So, I edited it out again, and then did:

```
sudo chattr +i ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config
```

which I hope it will prevent that lowgfx from slipping in again.

Comment: I don't have the reputation yet to add it to original question

Comment: This is not how this site works. You need to post your question (problem) and answer (solution) separately. Remove the solution part from the question and post it to "Your Answer" section below. It's completely fine to post answer to your own question :-)

Comment: My hope was, that someone with enough reputation would copy my text to the original question's answer, and then post a "done" as an answer here.

Comment: another alternative would have been a remark about how my suggestion was bad for reasons I didn't know...